# Changing Template Location in Wagtail

Tags: wagtail

I'm trying to direct `wagtail` to use a template in a centralised location at the top of the project tree. So for example:

```
Project
|_ HomePage
|_ Search
|_ Mypage
|_ templates
```

My project re-uses templates and I'd like to give UX/UI Developers access to a single folder rather than multiple sub-folders in multiple pages.

I've tried in `Mypage/models.py`

```
class AdvisorSummaryPages(Page):
    
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
     FieldPanel('intro'),
     InlinePanel('carousell', heading="Carousell Images")   
    ]
    
    template = "advisors.html"
```

With the following template setting in `Project/Project/settings/base.py`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
        ],
```

With no luck. I can't seem to find any solution on SO or through the documentation or Google that might work. There is a solution presented here using separate `model admins` but that doesn't work for me. How might I specify the location of the template differently to a subdirectory of templates in the MyPage App?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is how I organize templates and static assets.  I have a `themes` folder that is located in the main project folder with named theme subfolders within the `themes` folder. I then have the following in `settings/base.py`:

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(PROJECT_DIR)

THEMES_URL = '/themes/'
THEME_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, THEMES_URL.replace('/', ''), 'name_of_theme')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            THEME_PATH,
            ...other directories...,
        ],
... other TEMPLATES-RELATED CODE
     }
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(THEME_PATH, 'static'),
]


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

The `name_of_theme` folder in the `THEME_PATH` definition contains all of the templates and static files for the theme.  In order for the static files to be collected correctly, the folder structure for the css, js, etc. files within each theme folder needs to be:
`/themes/name_of_theme/static/name_of_theme/js (or css, etc.)/filename.js (or filename.css, etc.)`

The `/name_of_theme/static/name_of_theme/` namespacing is necessary for `collectstatic` to be able to collect the files correctly (see [Staticfile namespacing here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial06/) for more info).  When including a reference to a static file in a template, you then do:

`{% static 'name_of_theme/js/filename.js' %}`

The `STATICFILES_DIRS` definition is only set up for one theme.  You would need to change or add to that if you're using more than one theme.

Some time ago I also came across this Wagtail package:  [Wagtail Themes](https://github.com/moorinl/wagtail-themes).  It looks very interesting, but I'm not sure if it provides for handling static files organized within named theme folders as I describe above.

Comment: Thank you @DanSwain. Very useful information on the static file location. That solves my problem nicely.